# Is it possible to hide your backpack or helmet?

Tags: starbound

The Environmental Protection Packs (EPP) are essential to exploring certain hazardous planets, but they don't fit the outfit I'm going for - I mean, when was the last time you saw a cowboy wearing a spacesuit backpack? (Doctor Who doesn't count.)

It is possible to skin the EPP with another back piece, but so far all I've found is a tiger tail. Is it possible to hide the EPP and armor helmet altogether?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way do hide armor in vanilla Starbound. However, there are several mods available either from the Starbound website or the Steam Workshop that add invisible cosmetic armor, such as [this one](http://www.steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=729745066).